# Corner cases with GLR, precedence, and non-associativity: Intended Semantics?

Tags: parsing

Yes, I'm one of those insane people who have a parser-generator project. Minimal-LR(1) with operator-precedence was fairly straightforward. GLR support is next, preferably without making a mess of the corner cases around precedence and associativity (P&A).

Suppose you have an R/R conflict between rules with different precedence levels. A deterministic parser can safely choose the (first) rule of highest precedence. A parser designed to handle local ambiguity might not be sure, especially if the involved rules reduce to different non-terminals.

Suppose you have a R/R conflict between rules with- and without- precedence characteristics. A deterministic parser can reasonably choose the former. If you ask for GLR, do you mean to entertain both, or should the former clearly dominate the latter? Or is this scenario sufficiently weird as to justify rejecting the grammar?

Suppose you have an S/R/R conflict where only some of the participating rules have precedence, and maybe the look-ahead token does or doesn't have precedence. If P&A is all about what to do in front of the lookahead, then a non-precedent token should perhaps mean all options stay viable. But is that really the intended semantic here?

Suppose you have a nonassoc declaration on a terminal, and an S/R/R conflict where only ONE of the participating production rules hits the same non-associative precedence level. Then the other rule is clearly still viable to reduce, but what of the shift? Should we take it? What if we're mid-rule in a manner that doesn't trigger the same non-associativity problem? What if the look-ahead token is higher precedence than the remaining reduce, or the remaining reduce doesn't have precedence? How can we avoid accidentally constructing an invalid parse this way? Is there some trick with the parse-items to construct a shift-state that can't go wrong, or is this kind of thing beyond the scope of GLR parsing?

Also, how should semantic predicates interact with such ugly corner cases?

The simplest-thing-that-might-work is to treat anything involving operator-precedence in the same manner as a deterministic table-generator. But is that the intended semantic? Or perhaps: what kinds of declarations might grammar authors want to exert control over these weird cases?

Answer (score 4):

Traditional yacc-style precedence rules cannot be used to resolve reduce/reduce conflicts.

Yacc/bison "resolve" reduce/reduce conflicts by choosing the first production in the grammar file. This has nothing to do with precedence, and in the grammars where you would want to use a GLR parser, it is almost certainly not correct; you want the GLR parser to pursue all possible paths.

The bison GLR parser requires that ambiguity be resolved; that is, that the grammar be unambiguous. However, it has two "outs": first, it lets you use "dynamic precedence" declarations (which is a completely different concept, although it happens to use the same word); second, if that's not enough, it lets you provide your own resolution function.

Amongst other possibilities, a custom resolution function can accept both reductions, for example by inserting a branch in the AST. There are some theoretical issues with this approach for general parsing, but it works fine with real programming languages, which tend to not be ambiguous, or at least "not very ambiguous".

A typical case for dynamic precedence is implementing a (textual) rule like C++'s §9.8/1:

> There is an ambiguity in the grammar involving *expression-statements* and *declarations*: An *expression-statement* with a function-style explicit type conversion (8.2.3) as its leftmost subexpression can be indistinguishable from a *declaration* where the first *declarator* starts with a `(`. In those cases the *statement* is a *declaration*.

This rule cannot be expressed by a context-free grammar -- or, at least not in a way which would be readable -- but it is trivially expressible as a dynamic precedence rule.

As its name implies, dynamic precedence is dynamic; it's a rule applied at parse time by the parser. Bison's GLR algorithm only applies these rules if forced to; the parser handles multiline possible reductions normally (by maintaining all of them as possibilities). It is forced to apply dynamic precedence only when both possible reductions in a reduce/reduce conflict reduce to the same non-terminal.

By contrast, the yacc precedence algorithm, which as I mentioned only resolves shift/reduce conflicts, is static: it is compiled at generation time into the parse automaton (in effect, by removing actions from the transition tables), so the parser no longer sees the conflict.

This algorithm has been (justifiably) criticised for a variety of reasons, one of which is the odd behaviour of non-associative declarations in corner cases. Also, precedence rules do not compose well; because they are not scoped, they might end up accidentally applying to productions for which they were not intended. Not infrequently, they facilitate grammar bugs by hiding a conflict which should have been resolved by the grammar writer.

Best practice, therefore, is to avoid corner cases :-) Static precedence should be restricted to its originally-intended use cases: simple operator precedence and, possibly, documenting the "shift preferred" heuristic which resolves dangling-else resolution and certain grouped operator parses (iirc, there's a good example of this in the dragon book).

If you implement dynamic precedence -- and, honestly, there are good reasons not to -- then it should be applied to simple easily expressed rules like the C++ rule cited above: "if it looks like a declaration, it's a declaration." Even better would be to avoid writing ambiguous grammars; that particular C++ feature leads to the infamous "most vexatious parse", which has probably at some point  bitten every one of us who have tried writing C++ programs.

Comment: What don't you like about dynamic precedence (beside the unfortunate choice of name)? "Prefer interpretation X over interpretation Y" seems a perfectly reasonable statement in a non-LR(1) grammar intended for unambiguous parsing.

Comment: Great contribution to discussion, @rici! I'm not convinced it's the last word, though. For decades the advice was to avoid corner cases in LALR, but that advice didn't advance the state of the art. If the problem with an operator-precedence facility is the inadequacy of some algorithm, then I seek an improved algorithm. Your comment about scope has given me an idea how to blow the doors off the problem, though. So thanks!

Comment: @ian: SDL implements a scoped precedence system, iirc. But it doesn't handled dangling elses, which seems like a lack. I'm not sure what corner cases you're talking about in LALR, but fwiw my feeling is that a grammar should ideally function as documentation which automatically generates code, thus ensuring that the documentation does not diverge from the implemented language. To achieve that goal, the grammar needs to be readable and not just technically correct. But I am aware that that opinion is nit universal. Anyway, good luck with your project.

Comment: @ian: if you have to say "prefer X to Y", then the grammar actually is ambiguous :-) One example of why I think that is not always a great idea is already in the answer. The main reason I might choose to not implement dynamic precedence is that is it almost as easy to write as a walk over the constructed parse forest, which is not particularly difficult. However, I have been happy with bison's %dprec, used in moderation. In the C++ example, it's a perfectly good way of expressing the intent of the standard. But implementing it instead of making parse forests is a limitation.

Comment: "prefer X to Y" means the underlying CFG may be ambiguous, but the overall specification is not. The same is true of an operator-precedence sub-language. Dangling-else is just saying that `if` and `else` are right-associative and typically of extremely low precedence.

Comment: Completely agree on the "executable documentation" idea: https://github.com/kjosib/booze-tools says the grammar spec should be part of a markdown document explaining both lexical and phrase structure in plain language; how you process the parse tree is up to the application, which may be hosted in any suitable programming language from the same grammar definition.